# C++ Iterating through files in a directory: Is it bad practice?

Tags: c++, c++11

The question has been asked many times here: "How do I iterate through files in a directory in c++?"

I've seen the responses, typically suggesting to use an external library (usually boost filesystem) to handle this and the OS differences in implementation.

My question is: why? Why is this so difficult?
I'm new to the language and can't help but feel that I'm trying to overstep the bounds of idiomatic c++.

Is it more appropriate to implement a single file solution and use another language to implement the file iteration?

Comment: Is it really so difficult using a library? The ability to make and distribute libraries in `C++` is part of its power.

Comment: Flagged as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Would there be a more appropriate location to ask this question?

Comment: @i3rendn4v05: Perhaps you should reconsider whether the question *matters* at all. What does it matter why there is no filesystem support in the C++ standard library? The fact is that it isn't there. You can either deal with that reality or go to some other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative to other languages, C++ has a tiny standard library. This has its advantages (porting C++ to a new platform is much easier), but it also means that, to get a lot of things done, you're going to rely on external libraries.

Filesystem work has not, until C++17, been something that has been a part of the C++ standard. And even now, some people are resistant to the C++17 filesystem library because it doesn't work quite so well with certain types of underlying filesystems.

Note that many languages that have standard filesystem support don't support these platforms *at all*.

> I'm new to the language and can't help but feel that I'm trying to overstep the bounds of idiomatic c++.

If you're going to use C++, then you need to accept that you're going to have to go out and use other libraries for a lot of the stuff that many other languages give you for free. Using a library is how you get things done in C++; it's not "overstepping the bounds" of anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate the files in a directory in C++ without using platform-specific APIs. The core C++ language and the standard library do not provide any mechanism to obtain a directory listing and iterate through it. So in order to do this, you *must* use an external library or platform specific API.

Comment: Until C++17, that is.